# iterate through string and count occurrences

Tags: c#

This is the question:

- Write a program that reads a string from the console and prints in alphabetical order all letters from the input string and how many times each one of them occurs in the string.

It seemed interesting and not too complicated at first, but I couldn't solve it.

```
public static void Letters()
{
        string input;
        Console.Write("Enter a string:  ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        var chars = new List<char>();

        //To populate characters with the letters of the input but without repetition
        for(int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            if(!characters.Contains(input[index]))
                characters.Add(input[index]);
        }

        //To increment the counter corresponding to the character index
        int[] counter = new int[characters.Count];


        //Now what ?!

    }
```

My thinking is:

I create a collection to hold the letters of the input string, without any repetition.

Then I use an int array of the same size such that each int holds the number of times the corresponding letter has occurred in the input string.

I not only don't know how to implement this, but I have a feeling its not an ideal solution
to the problem. There's probably a query or a lambda expression that should make this easy
to implement and read.

Note: The question following this is of the same nature. The difference is that it asks 
to replace the repeated letters with a single one "aaabbbccc" to "abc".

I will appreciate if the logic is described. I will try to implement it on my own,
just point me to the logic.

EDIT:

This my answer using a dictionary

```
public static void Letters()
{
        string input;
        Console.Write("Enter a string:  ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        for(int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            char theKey = input[index]; //just for clarity

            if(!dict.ContainsKey(theKey))
                dict.Add(theKey, 1);
            else
                dict[input[index]]++;
        }

        foreach(var key in dict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", key, dict[key]);
        }
```

Comment: in which company interview you were asked to write this program?

Comment: Nope it is not a homework nor an interview, it is in this awesome website "www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-13-strings-and-text-processing/#_Toc362296495". The design of the site is kinda messy but it's exercises are excellent for a beginner like me :). This particular question is number 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionnary<String, int>
```

Key = string = letter  IE a,b,c,d,e,f.....
Int is number of occurence

So start by doing this :

```
Dictionnary.add(a,0)
...
Dictionnary.add(z,0);
```

And then read the string and do this

```
Dictionnary[letterFound ] += 1;
```

There is a better way knowing what is the value in ASCi of each letter to init the dictionnary, but i don't think is mandatory for such exercice.

Good luck

Comment: Excellen this worked. Only difference is that my dictionary is <char, it>. Check my update. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
var myString = "Hello";

var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach(var c in myString)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(c))
        dict.Add(c, 1);
    else
        dict[c]++;
}

var orderedDict = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key);

foreach(var kvp in orderedDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0}, Times: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Nicely orders the letters alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

For simple and readable solution use LINQ, GroupBy and anonymous types

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

var groupedLettersOrdered = input.GroupBy(x => x, (character, charCollection) =>
    new {Character = character, Count = charCollection.Count()})
    .OrderBy(x => x.Character);
foreach(var letterGroup in groupedLettersOrdered)
    Console.WriteLine("Character {0}, Count: {1}", letterGroup.Character, letterGroup.Count);
```

However `Dictionary<char, int>` solution will be (should be) faster and better for large strings

Comment: Thank you. I like this kind of LINQ and anonymous types solution, but since I did not formally start studying this part, It always goes over my head :).

Answer (score 0):

Consider first that a character has a binary representation (sequence of 1s and 0s) just like a scalar value. Consider also that for a Latin alphabet like English, the alphabetical order and numerical order of their equivalents correspond.

So... you could do something like this:

1. define an array of ints of a size large enough to accommodate all possible character values (arbitrarily, we could make it 256 for a UTF-8 string).
2. iterate over each character in the string; for each character, convert the character to its integer equivalent, use that as an index into the array and increment the value at that index.
3. iterate over the array and for each non-zero element, print out the character equivalent of the array index and the contents of the element (character count)

   ```
       string myString = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
       byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
       int[] counts = new int[256];
       foreach (var b in bytes)
       {
           counts[(int)b]++;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
       {
           if (counts[i] > 0)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", (char)(byte)i, counts[i]);
           }
       }
   ```

The above solution can easily be generalized to disregard case by performing GetBytes on myString.ToUpper(). To generalize to Unicode would be a little more work because you'd have to pair up the bytes in proper endian order.